# How to insert real-time data to database always from third-party API (max 1000) with pymysql/Python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-requests, pymysql

I am trying to request data from a third-party API, we got the API link like below:

```
GET /api/v4/dblines
```

Supposed we have to insert data from 2020-04-12 07:07:00, and we have original data before that DateTime, the API max/limit records are 1000, how to keep the script running and insert real-time data one by one all the time?

Below is the sample JSON data and my sample code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import requests

# getting json using requests
# data = requests.get('`https://api.example.com/api/v4/dblines?a=ABC123&b=1min&startTime=1586646420000&limit=1000`').json()
# data example
data = [
    [
        1593649440000,
        "2.9923453200",
        "2.9923453200",
        "2.0045299700",
        "2.0045299700",
        "2.2400009700",
        1593649499999,
        "2.0010870500",
        2,
        "2.0300009700",
        "2.0001359600",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1593649500000,
        "2.9923453297",
        "2.9923453297",
        "2.9923453297",
        "2.9923453297",
        "25.950000970",
        1593649559999,
        "2.1176054000",
        4,
        "25.950000970",
        "2.1176054000",
        "0"
    ]
]

# create df using json from API
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        # change aliases to column names here...
        'start_time',
        'alias1',
        'alias2',
        'alias3',
        'alias4',
        'alias5',
        'end_time',
        'alias6',
        'alias7',
        'alias8',
        'alias9',
        'alias10',
    ]
)
# drop unnecessary columns, duplicates, processing df, blabla etc...
# and init db connection
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}'
                       .format(user='db_user',
                               pw='db_password',
                               db='db_name'))
# insert df into db using connection 
# change if_exists if you need
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='table_name_here', if_exists='replace') # orginal data can't be replaced, how to change here?
```

Comment: Can't you use `Insert` method in a `while` loop ?

Comment: only while loop can't solve my problem, I have to let the startTime in request link be the parameter, in that way, I can let startTime = laststartTime + 59940000, I fount that `59940000ms` for 1000 records